# SDL Tridion 2011 CME is randomly hanging on IE 11

Tags: 2011, content-manager

SDL Tridion 2011 CME is constantly hanging on the IE 11 browser.

I have checked the settings of the browser and matched these with the [settings as stated in the documentation](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011/task_43B1609144D94562A394BB51FAC884B9?) but it didn't help.

I monitored the server response; it was not overloaded though several instances of CPU usage were in the 70% range. Memory usage is perfectly fine.

Please help me by suggesting what next steps to improve the CMS performance I can do on server and on my machine.

Comment: Have you installed some hotfix that adds support for IE 11? By default, 2011 only supports IE 7 and 8 as far as I recall.

Comment: Can you please tell me any hotfix link that I can to install

Comment: No I have not installed any hotfix yet, It was working fine since some days before on IE 11 as well.. But since last few days I started getting the hanging issues.

Comment: I don't know of any hotfixes to add support -- that's why I asked. We can certainly try to help you work it out, but in the end you are still using an unsupported browser so some things might just not work.

Comment: To troubleshoot it, maybe you can elaborate on what you mean by "hang". Does the browser literally become unresponsible (and never recovers)? What are you doing at the time that it happens? Is your IE running in compatibility view (and if so, what version is it using)?

Comment: Hangs means,, sometimes what operation I am doing in tridion CME is not responding like I clicked an page to open,, but it goes in waiting state,, some time clicking the left navigation have not any impacts etc. Many times when this situation come, it looks like my browser not responding and I have to close all the instances and reopen the browser.

Comment: Moreover it was working fine before some days.. I started getting this error since last week,,

Comment: Have you verified the scope of the problem? Does it happen only in IE11 or also in other browsers? Does it happen always or only during office hours (or only on Wednesdays, etc.)? Do other instances of Tridion CME work in the same browser?

Comment: on other browsers like Chrome it works fine,, and we are having a single CMS instance here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SDL Tridion 2011 supports IE 7, 8, 9 and 10 (hotfix required). We do not have support for IE 11 (this was added in to Tridion 2013), and do *not* intend to add this to a platform that is close to [being deprecated](http://help.sdl.com/support/web-content-management-products/).

PS - I heard that it works "fine" with IE 11 in compatibility mode.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,, Let me try this is compatibility mode for 1-2 days.. I will let you know in case I face any issue.